# Sed search one regex, return another

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following csv file:

```
hd1,100 
hd2,200
```

I'd like to change it so it reads like this:

```
hard1drive,100
hard2drive,200
```

I thought sed could help:

```
sed s'/hd[0-9]/hard[0-9]drive]/ < infile.csv
```

but instead of the desired output I get:

```
hard[0-9]drive,100
hard[0-9]drive,200
```

Is there any way I can 'capture' the number from the search parameter and insert it within the replace parameter within sed, or am I going to have to use another command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use capturing groups

```
 sed 's/hd\([0-9]\)/hard\1drive/'
```

Answer (score 0):

option without grouping:

```
kent$  echo "hd1,100 
hd2,200"|sed 's/d[0-9]/ar&drive/'                                                                                                                                           
hard1drive,100 
hard2drive,200
```